# iphone/ipad troubleshooting device crashes due to memory

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have an app that often crashes on the device (iPad), but not on the simulator, so any simulator debug tactics (MallocStackLogging for example) are not an option. What I usually get in the console is this:

```
Received memory warning. Level=1
Received memory warning. Level=2
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

My question is, at this point, is there something I can do to find out exactly what is causing the crash? Obviously it's a memory issue, but I'm having a hard time finding the cause. Is it a leak? Too much allocation? Is there anything besides "Run with Performance Tool > Leaks" that I can do to track down the problem?

Comment: why don't you want to use the Leaks tool? it is what it is for after all.

Comment: I am using the Leaks tool. My question is if there are any other methods of troubleshooting memory issues. Or is every possible memory issue detectable and displayed by Leaks?

Comment: No, *Leaks* does not detect every possible memory issue. It will flag some common problems, but nothing more. Use *Allocations* to see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 3):

Another good tool is the Static Analyzer.  Just click *Build and Analyze* in the *Build* menu and it will show you somewhere between many and most of your memory leaks.

Check out the [Apple Developer Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html) for more explanation on how to read the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use Instruments to see where all your memory is going.

I'd start with *Run with Performance Tool -> Allocations*.

Also, I find *Leaks* to be pretty conservative. I haven't seen a single false-positive from *Leaks*, but I've found plenty of leaks that *Leaks* didn't detect.

Comment: So what am I looking for in Allocations? It crashed with these stats: Live Bytes: 23.13 MB, #Living: 85455, #Transitory: 3856520, Overall Bytes: 475.43 MB, Overall: 3941975. Are any of those bad? Seems like it was hovering around 24-25MB of Live Bytes without crashing for a while.

Comment: First, make sure you're doing this in *Release on the device*. Watch *Live Bytes*. 25MB is pretty close to the maximum. You might want to drill down and find what's using all that memory.

Comment: Why would I receive a low memory warning when Live bytes is only around 10 MB? I can tell that I'm getting the warning because viewDidUnload gets called on some view controllers.

Comment: You get a warning when the *device* runs low on memory. In iOS 4 it might be that other applications are still using memory. Or that your application has (indirectly) gotten the OS to cache some items (images). I wouldn't worry about *just* warnings if your application isn't ejected. When it *is* ejected, you'll get a Low Memory crash log which tells you how many pages (4K each) your app was really using.